# Draw Routes on google map on click

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, routes

I need to draw routes on google map marker when a user click two marker the routes appear between markers which clicked by user.
In image you can see the multiple map marker I need when a user click on two markers routes appear between both map markers.
[image: In image you can see the multiple map marker I need when a user click on two markers routes appear between both map markers.]

```
    var map;
  function initMap() {



    var origin_place_id = null;
    var destination_place_id = null;
    var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    var travel_mode = google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING;
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      mapTypeControl: false,
      center: myCenter,
      zoom: 7,
      mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var markers = [
        ['Faisalabad, Pakistan', 31.4187,73.0791],
        ['Multan, Pakistan', 30.1984,71.4687],
        ['Lahore, Pakistan', 31.5546,74.3572],
        ['Sahiwal, Pakistan', 30.6612,73.1086]
    ];

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

    for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
    myCenter.extend(position);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map,
        title: markers[i][0]
    });
        map.fitBounds(myCenter);
    }
    var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
        this.setZoom(8);
        google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
    });

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('go'), 'click',route);
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;

    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

    var origin_input = document.getElementById('origin-input');
    var destination_input = document.getElementById('destination-input');
    var modes = document.getElementById('mode-selector');



    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(modes);

    var origin_autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(origin_input);
    origin_autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
    var destination_autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(destination_input);
    destination_autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);


    function setupClickListener(id, mode) {
      var radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
      radioButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        travel_mode = mode;
      });
    }
    setupClickListener('changemode-walking', google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING);
    setupClickListener('changemode-transit', google.maps.TravelMode.TRANSIT);
    setupClickListener('changemode-driving', google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING);


    function expandViewportToFitPlace(map, place) {
        if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
        map.setZoom(17);
      }
    }

    origin_autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
      var place = origin_autocomplete.getPlace();
      if (!place.geometry) {
        window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
        return;
      }
      expandViewportToFitPlace(map, place);


      origin_place_id = place.place_id;
      route(origin_place_id, destination_place_id, travel_mode,
            directionsService, directionsDisplay);
    });

    destination_autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
      var place = destination_autocomplete.getPlace();
      if (!place.geometry) {
        window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
        return;
      }

      expandViewportToFitPlace(map, place);
    $('#go').click(function(){
        var origin_input = document.getElementById('origin-input').value;
        var res = origin_input.split(",");
        var bc = res[0];
        var destination_input = document.getElementById('destination-input').value;
        var res = destination_input.split(",");
        var bd = res[0];

        destination_place_id = place.place_id;
        route(origin_place_id, destination_place_id, travel_mode,
            directionsService, directionsDisplay);
        });
    });
    $('#mode-selector').hide();
    $('#go').click(function(){
        //$('#go').hide(250);
        $('#mode-selector').show(250);
    });


    function route(origin_place_id, destination_place_id, travel_mode,
    directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
      if (!origin_place_id || !destination_place_id) {
        return;
      }
      directionsService.route({
        origin: {'placeId': origin_place_id},
        destination: {'placeId': destination_place_id},
        travelMode: travel_mode
      }, 
    function(response, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        } else {
          window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple click event</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      // JavaScript Document
var map;
  function initMap() 
  {
    var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var directionsDisplay;
     var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
 
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
       mapTypeControl: false,
       center: myCenter,
       zoom: 7,
       mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     });

  var markers = [
   ['Faisalabad, Pakistan', 31.4187,73.0791],
   ['Multan, Pakistan', 30.1984,71.4687],
   ['Lahore, Pakistan', 31.5546,74.3572],
   ['Sahiwal, Pakistan', 30.6612,73.1086]
  ];
   directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

     var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

     for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
   //var myLatLng = {lat: markers[i][1], lng: markers[i][2]};
     var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
     myCenter.extend(pos);
     marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: pos,
        map: map,
        title: markers[i][0]
     });
        map.fitBounds(myCenter);
  
  var  route = 0;
  var pos_source=0;
  var pos_destination=0;
  
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
    route++;
    if(route==1)
    {
     pos_source = this.position;
    }
    if(route==2)
    {
     pos_destination = this.position;
     route = 0;
     
     var start = new google.maps.LatLng(pos_source.lat(), pos_source.lng());
     var end = new google.maps.LatLng(pos_destination.lat(), pos_destination.lng());
     var request = {
      origin: start,
      destination: end,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
     };
     directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
       directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      }
     });
    }
                
    }
        })(marker, i));
     }
  }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is keep track of the two markers clicked by the user. For this create a global array of markers. On each marker click check if the marker array is:

- Empty: push the current marker(which has just been clicked)
- Contains one element: call the showRoute function and pass the current marker(destination) and the marker present in the array(source) as parameter. Use google map direction api to draw the route. Empty the markers array.